# Highcharts: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

So I have this chart built out and it works except it keeps throwing the error Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined. I am reloading the chart on window resize so that the html labels reload in correct positions.

It's a double donut chart and shows/hides content based on the selected slice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try to modify options.chart.renderTo, something like this ``renderTo: $('#charts-container')``. And check div#charts-container is uniq.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but doesn't work. it sends back 

Uncaught TypeError: a.setAttribute is not a function

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'm missed point of problem. ``addClass("currentItem", 1000, callback(target))`` what you are doing here? ``addClass`` has one parameter and it is string or function. And callback function will be called immediately in this case. Also your callback has no incoming parameters

Comment: I corrected the callback parameter issue. The error occurs on window resize. So chart is undefined when it's resized? Even though it's calling the same function it uses when it loads it?

Comment: D.reflow @ highcharts.js?ver=1:213


    D.initReflow.b @ highcharts.js?ver=1:213

    m.event.dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:1

    m.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:1

Comment: Try to make chart variable global and add this line ``if(chart) chart.destroy();`` before you reinitialize it. If you make jsfiddle of this, im sure that i can help you more easily.

Comment: What is the reason of creating new chart each time when you resize?

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan I'm using "useHTML" for the datalabels. They need to respond to the responsive css, so I found that reloading the chart on resize  accomplishes that goal.

Comment: @aleksey krivstov - https://jsfiddle.net/dpsn9gx8/3/, I tried adding if (chart)...but it that statement is never true so it doesn't destroy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you  define `var chart` variable in `createChart` function, so it always will be undefined - use only one definition (the one on top), later just assign chart to that variable. Anyway, I see two solutions:

- use `setTimeout()` in `resize` event, to render chart with a delay. Not a reliable solution, because user can play around with width of the browser and something may be broken again
- wrap `initReflow` method to check if chart exists, like this:

  ```
  (function(H, HA) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype.initReflow = function () {
      var chart = this,
          reflow = function (e) {
              if(chart && chart.options) {
                  chart.reflow(e);
              }
          };


      HA.addEvent(window, 'resize', reflow);
      HA.addEvent(chart, 'destroy', function () {
          HA.removeEvent(window, 'resize', reflow);
      });
    });
  })(Highcharts, HighchartsAdapter)
  ```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dpsn9gx8/7/

**Edit:**
Since Highcharts 4.1.10 Highcharts adapter is built-in, so remove it and use Highcharts: https://jsfiddle.net/dpsn9gx8/11/

Comment: Fus

Thank you. I also recieved another answer which also solved the issue. Adding in  reflow: false resolved the issue as well. Is there a big difference between the two?

chart: {
     reflow: false,
            ...

Comment: Indeed, `chart.reflow` may be better solution, since it's easier to setup. The result should be the same: disabled chart-resize on window-resize event.

Comment: so it appears that this solution no longer works. It now throws an error Highcharts Adapter is undefined. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Edited answer - this is caused by change in Highcharts in 4.1.10.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks again!